# CRF Training: Max-margin vs max-likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, conditional-random-field, max-margin

I'm trying to use PyStruct's CRF implementation. In its [user guide](https://pystruct.github.io/user_guide.html#conditional-random-field-like-graph-models), it says the following:

> I call these models Conditional Random Fields (CRFs), but this a
>   slight abuse of notation, as PyStruct actually implements perceptron
>   and max-margin learning, not maximum likelihood learning. So these
>   models might better be called Maximum Margin Random Fields.

How are max margin and max likelihood related? Will they give similar answers?

It seems like max-margin learning is discriminative, while max-likelihood is generative, but I'd like to know more than that.

Answer (score 1):

All these methods are discriminative. They do exactly the same computation at prediction time. The difference is at training time: optimization objective is different. For the same training data these models can assign different values to model parameters after training. Max-margin methods are generalization of SVMs to structured prediction; CRF is a generalization of Logistic Regression for structured prediction. In practice they should give similar results.